# Update SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to update a specific row in my database. I'm trying to update a single data with a button. But when I run the app the database is not updated and Ive not received any error. What did I do wrong?

Here's my code.

In my java class:

```
  public void Favorite1(View view){

    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();
    String favorite_1 = "FIZO MAWAR";

    loginDataBaseAdapter.updateEntry(favorite_1);
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    finish();

}
```

My database:

```
public void updateEntry(String favorite_1) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("FAVORITE1", favorite_1);

    db.update("LOGIN", values, "USERNAME = ?", null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do use a *where* clause but pass `null` as its arguments. See the docs for the [update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method. Assuming a column named "FAVORITE1" exists in the "LOGIN" table, the correct usage will be:

```
db.update("LOGIN", values, "USERNAME = ?", new String[]{username});
```

If the `favorite_1` parameter already represents a username (which I tend to infer from your code), use it:

```
db.update("LOGIN", values, "USERNAME = ?", new String[]{favorite_1});
```